# Connecting a database from the server then running the UI (python) on the desktop

Tags: python, database

So we tried to connect our database on a server. The UI language we use is python but the UI code wont run. It only displays the code. We tried to install the python in the server but it won't run. However we want to run the UI code through our desktop but the database is from the server. How can we do it?

Comment: Without any more information it is impossible to know the answer. How do you run the python code? What exactly do you mean with "UI language", are you talking about a webframework like django or flask that runs on the server? If so, how did you deploy? If not, what do you use for a GUI?

Comment: Put a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the question.

Comment: we use the python language to make a user interface(UI) for our database and when we tried to implement it on the server it only shows the code of the python program and won't run.. so we decided we want to import the python program real-time and run it on our desktop since it has a python program.. (we can't implement the python on the server so this is what we want to do)